# Travis is Failing without showing a reason

Tags: mysql, typescript, mocha.js, travis-ci, chai-http

I am trying to build my project through travis-ci, but unknown error is happening when travis tries to test the project through mocha. i know the issue is not with mysql since the connection is there and scripts are working.

I am testing using
- ts-node/register
- Mocha
- Chai
- Chai-http
- mySQL (using pool)

The test is working fine locally, but on travis it is failing. i am thinking that it might be something with ts-node/register, in travis.

1 - i have tried remove the test completely and the build was fixed. but when i try to test it fails miserably.

### package.json

```
{
    "name": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "ENV='PRODUCTION' node dist/app.js --verbose",
        "debug": "node --inspect dist/app.js",
        "dev": "ENV='DEVELOPMENT' nodemon src/app.ts --verbose",
        "build": "tsc -p .",
        "test": "ENV='TEST' mocha -r ts-node/register test/{,dbMappers}/**.test.ts --exit; ",
      "test:awesome": "ENV='TEST' mocha -r ts-node/register test/{,dbMappers}/**.test.ts --reporter mochawesome --exit; "
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "app-root-path": "^2.2.1",
        "bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "colors": "^1.3.3",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "mysql": "^2.17.1",
        "uuid": "^3.3.2",
        "winston": "^3.2.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/app-root-path": "^1.2.4",
        "@types/bcrypt": "^3.0.0",
        "@types/body-parser": "^1.17.0",
        "@types/chai": "^4.2.0",
        "@types/chai-http": "^4.2.0",
        "@types/colors": "^1.2.1",
        "@types/cors": "^2.8.5",
        "@types/dotenv": "^6.1.1",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
        "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.2",
        "@types/mocha": "^5.2.7",
        "@types/mysql": "^2.15.6",
        "@types/node": "^12.6.8",
        "@types/uuid": "^3.4.5",
        "@types/winston": "^2.4.4",
        "chai": "^4.2.0",
        "chai-http": "^4.3.0",
        "mocha": "^6.2.0",
        "mochawesome": "^4.1.0",
        "nodemon": "^1.19.1",
        "ts-node": "^8.3.0",
        "typescript": "^3.5.3"
    }
}
```

### .travis.yml

```
language: node_js
node_js: 
   - "stable"
directories:
   - "node_modules"
services:
   - mysql
cache:
   - "node_modules"
before_script:
   - mysql -u root -e "CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxxx'"
   - mysql -u root -e 'CREATE DATABASE backend;'
   - mysql -u root -e 'SHOW DATABASES'
   - mysql -u root -e "GRANT ALL ON backend.* TO 'test'@'localhost';" 
   - npm install
env:
   - ENV: 'TEST'
```

The Travis repo 
https://travis-ci.com/moh682/hbas-system-api

The error that travis expose is only this.

> yyy@1.0.0 test /home/travis/build/xxx/yyy
>   ENV='TEST' mocha -r ts-node/register test/{,dbMappers}/**.test.ts --exit;

xxx = username | yyy = repo name

Comment: Can you share a link to the travis public travis build log, so that the full message can be seen?

Comment: yes.
https://travis-ci.com/moh682/hbas-system-api
thank you

Comment: great, thanks. And to confirm does the test work when you try to run it locally?

Comment: yes it works perfectly without any issues.

Comment: i mean that the test running in local works fine. but the error is still there :(